# Local storage availability

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

In what cases local storage is undefined/unavailable?
One case I know about is when we define

```
var localStorage
```

as a property of the window object in the global scope.
Other case I may think about is when a user disables some abilities of the browser. Can someone clarify the possible situations of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

*There is no way to disable localStorage from a user point of view.* (Actually it seems it is possible, read more at https://superuser.com/questions/298922/chrome-chromium-disable-html5-localstorage-and-databases-for-all-webpages-or)

But some old browsers do not support this feature.

As @Joakim stated, you can find the list of all browser compatible online at http://caniuse.com/#search=local%20storage

Basically it won't be available in IE7 and lower, in old versions of Safari and Opera as well.

[image: Screenshot of compatible browsers]